# Writing Log File Error file_put_contents(/var/www/html/myproject/ulogs/my-log.log): Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, apache

I have inherited a PHP application and need to investigate various issues. I am not a PHP programmer so bear with me.

I wrote a function to log messages to a custom log file.

```
<?php
function my_logger($log_msg)
{
error_log("USER INFO:::::",0);
error_log(get_current_user());
error_log(exec('whoami'));
    file_put_contents('/var/www/html/myproject/ulogs/my-log.log', date('G:i:s') . ">>$ " . $log_msg . "\n", FILE_APPEND);

}
```

After a lot of 500 errors and no information  I discovered that the following line is being written to the error_log.log

> PHP Warning:
> file_put_contents(/var/www/html/myproject/ulogs/my-log.log): Failed to
> open stream: Permission denied in
> /var/www/html/myproject/app/lib/log_fns.php on line 11

I have put in a call to get_current_user and whoami  which shows me:

> ```
> [07-Apr-2021 14:26:04 UTC] USER INFO::::
> [07-Apr-2021 14:26:04 UTC] root 
> [07-Apr-2021 14:26:04 UTC] apache
> ```

I am calling this at the moment from a simple php page called  at http:///test_log.php:

```
<?php

require("/var/www/html/myproject/app/lib/log_fns.php");

//phpinfo();

my_logger("This is a test message from test_log.php");

?>
```

I  tried to chmod the files to 777 in the ./lib directory but was still getting this error. I have hard coded the path you can see above creating the ulogs directory.

I have tried combinations of chmod the ulogs directory to 777 and chown the directory to apache:apache but still get this error.

Any ideas where I can look next or how to solve?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html/myproject/ulogs/
```

With this work you `file_put_contents` can generate or edit the file in this directory

Comment: Did this, and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and no changing of file/folder permissions worked. The issue in the end was SELinux, which is setup as enforcing by default on CentOS.

To disable it, edit `/etc/selinux/config`, and change

```
SELINUX=enforcing
```

to

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Reboot and it should work.